# Windows reports error when trying to install package using pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I installed pipenv by following the instructions [here](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv).  From the Windows command prompt I ran

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

which returned the message

```
Successfully installed pipenv-5.3.3
```

Now I want to install the `requests` package using pipenv, so I ran

```
pipenv install requests
```

but this returned

```
'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have added the path

```
C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages
```

to my Windows path environment variable, but I still receive the same error.
How can I install the `requests` package using pipenv?

---

EDIT:  As I have remnants of Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 on my system, I'm going to uninstall everything and start anew.  (I've just started learning Python and I want to keep this as simple as possible.)

Comment: does `python -m pipenv` work in place of `pipenv`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen worked for me! Thank you

Comment: @NicoMüller [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46041892/5827215) elaborates on why that works, if you are thankful an upvote would be nice. :)

Comment: just did it :- )

Answer (score 151):

I have a similar setup and faced a similar problem, but the solution I found was fairly simple. All of my PATH variables were already correct (from Python 3 the Windows Installer automatically does all of this).

### The problem

The problem actually arises because of *conflicting* installations of **virtualenv**.

### Fix

To address this problem you need to simply run the following commands:

1. First, remove your current version of virtualenv: `pip uninstall virtualenv`
2. Then, remove your current version of pipenv: `pip uninstall pipenv`
3. When you are asked `Proceed (y/n)?` just enter `y`. This will give you a clean slate.
4. Finally, you can once again install pipenv and its dependencies: `pip install pipenv`

This will also install the latest version of **virtualenv**.

### Testing if it worked

Just enter `pipenv --version` in the command prompt and you should see the desired output.

#### Notes

I know this sounds the mundane, but it is actually the solution for Windows systems. You do not need to modify any of your system environment variables (**please do not add site-packages to your environment variables**).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: This work for me, my mistake was that i install virtualenv first, was not aware that this was included in pipenv, thank you!

Comment: Worked as well, there is something fundamentally broken with Python dependency managers and virtual environments. I had problems on Linux , Windows and not even proficient QA engineers using Python on daily basis could help me. Corrupted environments, broken pip, reinstalling python etc. etc. as reigning language in 2019 Python community should sort out their mess. Javascript did with npm, Java long time with maven and gradle. Python is doing some weird tango.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks mate!

Comment: helped me in 2020

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Needs to be accepted as best answer. Thanks mate

Comment: Thanks thats aweswome.. not sure how it happened but it worked

Comment: Did not work for me. *Edit:* oops, pip gave me a clear log message saying `The script virtualenv is installed in '/home/pi/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.` - I guess this is something else that can come up

Comment: @Alter thanks, I didn't read log :) you saved me some time :)

Comment: To the contrary, it did not help me, had to manually add the correct dir to path... Just search for "pipenv" on C:

Comment: I love you. Marry me. NOW.

Answer (score 29):

`python -m pipenv` may work for you, (or `python3 -m pipenv` or `py 3 -m pipenv`) this is telling python to run the module `pipenv` instead of the terminal shortcut which requires python's script `/bin` folder to be on your terminals `PATH` variable which often the installer gives a warning that no one pays attention to it.

---

Just to show they are equivalent when I installed `pipenv` and run `which pipenv` it points to a file like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pipenv` which looks like this:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pipenv import cli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(cli())
```

so it removes `.pyw` or `.exe` from the executable name then call `pipenv.cli.cli()`. It is likely there is a file like this on your machine it just didn't add python's `/bin` folder to your system `PATH` so it isn't accessible. (and you almost certainly were given a warning at some point but it wasn't sufficiently noisy for your attention level)

the module `pipenv.__main__` which is run when using `python -m pipenv` looks like this:

```
from .cli import cli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Which calls `pipenv.cli.cli()`.  So this main module absolutely does the same effective thing.

Comment: Using `python -m pipenv requests` returned `Traceback` followed by a dozen file/line number specifications and `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pipfile'`.  When I run a program with the line`import requests` Python returns the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`.  BTW, I appreciate your detailed answer, but it's beyond my level of understanding and I don't know how to implement it in Windows.  So maybe a better question would be _What's the easiest way to install a package?_ (I tried `python -m pip install requests` with no improvements.)

Comment: @Robert using `python -m pip install` is my suggestion for installing packages, if that is resulting in error I'd be interested in what that error is.  also when you run python programs how do you do that?

Comment: I decided to cleanly reinstall Python as I had remnants of two different versions on my system.  I'm still not able to install packages, and my follow-up question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46042829/4945268)

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 25):

to solve this problem i need to start my CMD as administrator.

1. pip uninstall pipenv
2. pip install pipenv

To test this new configuration, you can write pipenv --version

Answer (score 7):

Use **python -m pipenv** instead of just pipenv, it should work. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following to Path environmental variable:

```
C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

instead of the `\site-package`, as that is where **pipenv.exe** is installed (at least for me).

Comment: Thanks, but I just reinstalled Python into a folder where I had write access.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042921/4945268

Answer (score 2):

use this cmd solve my problem :

```
python -m pipenv install django==2.1
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to @Srivats Shankar. In case you have tried what he said and it did not work, hope you did not forget to check your python path? If you have more than a single python version installed, doing `pip uninstall virtualenv` or `pip uninstall pipenv` might not help solve the problem.

Every `python version` is generally supposed to have its own `pip` installed. What you would do in this case is:

```
`-python -version_to_uninstall_virtualenv_from -m pip uninstall virtualenv; py --version -m pip uninstall virtualenv
-python -version_to_uninstall_pipenv_from -m pip uninstall pipenv; py --version -m pip uninstall pipenv`
```

Then you install `pipenv` with a similar command:

```
 `-python -version_to_install_pipenv_on -m pip install pipenv; py --version -m pip uninstall pipenv`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an error like you sed and I just reinstalled pipenv and it fixed.
I used this command:

```
pip install pipenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages
```

it should be

```
C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

after that, try **closing** and **reopening** the terminal

Answer (score 0):

check warnings after installing pipenv. sometimes pipenv location not registered in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed several different situations with multiple python versions installed.

A preferred solution would be to use:

`python -m pip install pipenv`

This command for Python3.7 instance generates executables in
`C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts` and it made setting up other packages easier.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
python -m pip install pipenv
```

and then

```
python -m pipenv install requests
```

Answer (score -2):

Windows is not officially supported, I think.

ref: https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/issues/70

Answer (score -10):

Please check that pipenv is installed in your system by run following command in command promt:

```
pipenv --version
```

If it returns error, so please install again and set environment variable path in your system

Comment: the question states that they get an error saying `'pipenv' is not recognized as a command` so I don't see how this would help

Comment: This seems more suited for a comment then an answer