# Can't install packages in Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I just reinstalled Python 3.6, but when I try to install packages, Windows returns errors.  First I tried installing package `BeautifulSoup` from the Windows command prompt:

```
python -m pip install BeautifulSoup
```

but this returns the following error:

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iiyyxs2o\BeautifulSoup\setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-iiyyxs2o\BeautifulSoup\
```

Then I tried installing package `requests`:

```
python -m pip install requests
```

but this returns

```
C:\Program Files\Python36>python -m pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi, idna, chardet, urllib3, requests
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\certifi'
```

What do I need to do so that pip successfully installs packages?

Comment: can you try: run the command prompt with _elevated privileges_ (administrator). Then use `pip install beautifulsoup` (lowercase); And retry `requests` as well, that should work

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In the administrative command prompt, Windows reports the same error after `pip install beautifulsoup`

Comment: what about `requests` ?

Comment: `pip install requests` worked fine :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is for Python 2 only. For Python 3 install [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

The second problem seems obvious: you don't have write-access to `C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages` and subdirectories.

Comment: Install Python into a directory where the user has write-access. C:\\Python36 is the most standard place.