# How do I run pipenv, if I always get the same error?

Tags: python, runtime-error, pipenv

I'm trying to run 'pipenv' on Windows 10, and it doesn't want to run... The error is receive is below

````
PS C:\Users\charl\Documents\Python\Face Recognition> pipenv shell
pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try       
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipenv shell
+ ~~~~~~
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException```
````

Comment: try to check if you have install pipenv already in your system. it look like you dont. https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/

Comment: I have installed it, today

Comment: check it using the command pip list to look if you have installed right

Comment: There are lots of possible solutions here, including altering your path or calling python -m pipenv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041719/windows-reports-error-when-trying-to-install-package-using-pipenv

Comment: It still doesn't work...

```
pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipenv --python 3.7
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python -m pipenv instead of just pipenv, it should work. Best of luck to you.