# Pipenv is not recognized

Tags: python, shell, pip, pipenv, pipenv-install

I get this error every time I try to verify my pipenv version

'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling
as well as adding the path to the system environment variables but nothing seems to work

I know I have installed pipenv but it still wont recognized the command pipenv at all

EDIT:
The Fix for this problem was running this

```
-m python pipenv shell
```

rather than this

```
pipenv shell
```

However once i was in the shell i could not run commands like this

```
-m python pipenv --version
```

Instead I had to do this

```
-m python3 pipenv --version
```

From what I have seen no one seems to have answer as to why the syntax is like this and why I have to declare -m python before every Command, as ive seen other devs run commands to python without having to declare -m python.

I am running windows 10 if this is important information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows reports error when trying to install package using pipenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041719/windows-reports-error-when-trying-to-install-package-using-pipenv)

Comment: No i already tried uninstalling and reinstalling virtualenv

Comment: Isn't it `pipenv`?

Comment: Silly question, but is  _pipenv_ in your PATH, and does it have the x-bit set?

Comment: @user1934428 "*…is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file…*" suggests that it's a graphical environment that doesn't have executable bits. ;-)

Comment: @php : What is a _graphical environment_??? At least on Linux or MacOS, to run a program you need rights to execute it; I believe it is similar on Windows, though their rights management is a bit more complicated.

Comment: hello, did you get any solution?