# 'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, pipenv

I am a beginner in python so please be gentle and if you do have an answer please provide details.

I just installed the most recent python version 3.10 after making sure to delete all previous installations (including anaconda). I am positive my system is clear of any prior installation.

after installing python 3.10 I open my terminal and run the following:

```
pip list
```

which outputs:

```
pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.2.3
setuptools 57.4.0
```

Then I install pipenv

```
pip install pipenv
```

which outputs

```
  WARNING: The script virtualenv-clone.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Giulio\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Giulio\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pipenv-resolver.exe and pipenv.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Giulio\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed backports.entry-points-selectable-1.1.0 certifi-2021.10.8 distlib-0.3.3 filelock-3.3.2 pipenv-2021.5.29 platformdirs-2.4.0 six-1.16.0 virtualenv-20.10.0 virtualenv-clone-0.5.7
```

Finally:

```
pipenv
'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now I can see that the terminal spits out 3 warning concerning paths not included in Environment Variables.
I don't understand why pipenv gets installed in user folders.
Indeed my python installation is in C:\Program Files (as I made sure to set up during installation):

```
where python
C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
```

If I run:

```
python -m pipenv
```

pipenv does his thing.
So Ok I resolve to use it like this (despite all tutorials have it easy).
I proceed to create a virtual environment in a given folder

```
python -m pipenv shell
```

Everything works and I see the output:

```
Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\Giulio\.virtualenvs\project-dhMbrBv2
```

Finally, I inspect the .virtualenvs related folder:

```
01/11/2021  10:58    <DIR>          .
01/11/2021  10:58    <DIR>          ..
01/11/2021  10:54                42 .gitignore
01/11/2021  10:54                38 .project
01/11/2021  10:58                 0 contents.txt
01/11/2021  10:54    <DIR>          Lib
01/11/2021  10:54               319 pyvenv.cfg
01/11/2021  10:54    <DIR>          Scripts
               4 File(s)            399 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  660,409,012,224 bytes free
```

Now... shouldn't there be a BIN folder as well?
For instance I would like to set the interpreter in VSCode.

I cannot understand why I am getting all of these small inconsistencies.
Gladly appreciate any help!

EDIT (1):
So apparently there is no `\bin` folder because I am using windows:
In windows the `\Scripts` folder is created instead.
But the problem of pipenv not running without the preemptive call to python persists.

Answer (score 22):

You can refer to this answer solution with the highest upvotes - [Windows reports error when trying to install package using pipenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041719/windows-reports-error-when-trying-to-install-package-using-pipenv/46041892#46041892)

Or can refer to this GitHub issue on pipenv - [github link](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3101)

1. First, remove your current version of virtualenv: `pip uninstall virtualenv`
2. Then, remove your current version of pipenv: `pip uninstall pipenv`
3. When you are asked Proceed (y/n)? just enter y. This will give you a clean slate.
4. Finally, you can once again install pipenv and its dependencies: `pip install pipenv`
5. Check installation with `pipenv --version`

Answer (score 2):

Did follow the suggested steps, but did not work,
Later, set the `C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts` to "PATH" environment variable and relaunched the cmd.

It worked like a charm...

Note: During the installation itself it warns to set the `C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts` to "PATH" env variable

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Advanced System Settings in Control Panel
2. Click on Environmental Variables
3. Under System Variables Look for PATH (If you don't see it then you can click on New and create one).
4. Click on Edit and in Variable Value Paste Link Which Look Like This C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts
5. Click Ok

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot.

Please type these commands one by one to set pipenv.

```
pip list
pip install pipenv
pipenv
where python
python -m pipenv
python -m pipenv shell
```

If not working restart your windows, Linux, or macOS operating system and always you need to install the current version software or machine. Like python and pip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Search for Environmental Variables on your search and go on it

Click on the "Environmental Variables" Button

Under System Variables Look for PATH (If you don't see it then you can click on New and create one):

Click on Edit and in Variable Value Paste Link Which Look Like This C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts
Click Ok

Create this path too:
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

> i also faced this problem i tried

```
 pip unistall virtualenv
```

> and again

```
`pip install pipenv`
```

> it did not work then i just used

```
`python -m pipenv install [dependecy name]`
```

> and it worked

Comment: What is the additional insight which you contribute beyond existing answers? Please [edit] to make that more obvious. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75445610/7733418

Comment: Also I suspect that `pip unistall virtualenv and pipenv` is more spoken English (with the same meaning as linked answer) than correct syntax. Please double check, maybe explain the way it works.