# I can't run `pipenv install <package>`: "'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Tags: python, windows, pipenv

Whenever I enter

```
pipenv install django
```

in the cmd, an error appears:

> 'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I can run:

```
pip install pipenv
```

and:

```
pip install django
```

Comment: create a venv with cmd https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795302/pipenv-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by re-installing python then checked the check box called " add python to PATH " and it worked perfect with no errors

Answer (score 0):

Checking "add python to PATH" when installing Python will only work for Python and pip commands. However, while installing "**pipenv**" using "**pip install pipenv**" command, **pipenv** will be installed but it might not be added to the PATH environment variables and you have to do it manually. Doing this, most probably the error "**pipenv is not recognized...**" will disappear. I solved this issue when I realized **pipenv** is not added to the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

**pip show pipenv**

**Update the PATH**: If pipenv is installed but not found in the PATH, you need to add it. Here is how you can add a new location to the PATH:

**For Windows:**

Search for "Environment Variables" on your computer (you can use the search bar).
Click on "Edit the system environment variables."
Click on the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom.
Under "System Variables" find the "Path" variable, select it, and click on "Edit."